# Using Gimp and clone tool. Source selection selects center of four pixels

Tags: pixel, selection, gimp

I am using gimp to make tilesets. When I use the clone tool and hold ctrl to select the source, the selection is in the center of four pixels instead of just one pixel.  I don't know if I am doing something wrong or if there is a setting to change this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is a pic.
[image]

Comment: Don't hold CTRL?

Comment: In my opinion i would recommend switching to paint.net , you will find it easier to use.

Comment: Holding CTRL is how you set the source in order to clone.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! It is just a glitch.  After you ctrl click and start cloning, the source mask stays on a single pixel.